# Python 2 - "For counting loop"

Tags: python, for-loop

I am working on a project for school in python 2 and I am having a lot of trouble with one of the problems:

> Write a program that computes the following sum:
>       sum = 1.0/1 + 1.0/2 + 1.0/3 + 1.0/4 + 1.0/5 + .... + 1.0/N
>       N is an integer limit that the user enters.

```
For example:
Enter N: 4
Sum is: 2.08333333333
```

The code I currently have written is:

```
NumOfN = int(input("What is N? : "))
total = 0
for i in range (NumOfN):
  NextNum = 1.0/(NumOfN)
  total = NextNum
  NumOfN = NumOfN-1
print "the sum is", total
```

However whenever I run this I get an **output of "1.0"** any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Thank you.

Comment: This can be done in one line with a list comprehension and `sum`. `total = sum([1.0/x for x in range(1,NumOfN+1)])`

Comment: @erip the things you can do with python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not incrementing `total` with itself and `NextNum`. I changed `total = NextNum` to `total += NextNum`:

```
NumOfN = int(input("What is N? : "))
total = 0
for i in range(NumOfN):
  NextNum = 1.0/(NumOfN)
  total += NextNum
  NumOfN = NumOfN-1
print "the sum is ", total
```

or more simply:

```
NumOfN = int(input("What is N? : "))
runningTab = []
for i in range(NumOfN, -1, -1):
    if i != 0:
        runningTab.append(1.0/(i))

print "the sum is ", sum(runningTab)
```

It is better to use lists and sum at the end than to keep a running tally of numbers.

Comment: @erip well it does reduce the number of variables used and improves upon a few things. Less code is simplified

Answer (score 0):

Second line of the for loop:

```
total = NextNum
```

The variable `total` should have `NextNum` added to it, not just reassigned. This is because `total` must be added over and over by adding `NextNum` to itself. Let's change that to:

```
total = total + NextNum
```

This would mean: `total` needs to add `NextNum` to itself, so we will add them together so that the new `total` is now equal to the old `total + NextNum`.

A side note:

You may have noticed that @heinst used `+=` in his line of code, `total += NextNum`. This is the same as `total = total + NextNum` , but it is like an abbreviation. You can do this with `+=` , `-=` , `*=`,and `/=`. All of them are ways to abbreviate the line of code that would reassign a variable after doing some arithmetic on it.

With that being said, the following line of code:

```
NumOfN = NumOfN-1
```

Can become:

```
NumOfN -= 1
```

This is an abbreviation.

Comment: I never knew I could do `NumOfN -= 1` like that, that will make life a lot easier, thanks

Comment: No problem :D @TheRIProgrammer